# Need some advice to solve this integral $\int\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to use this subtitution $t=\tan(x/2)$. But I don´t get anywhere. I've tried $t=\tan(x)$ too.  Appreciate your help.

$$\int\dfrac{\sin^2x}{1+\sin^2x}\mathrm dx$$

Comment: What do mean by "I don't get anywhere"? Have you got the equivalent form of the integral after the change of variables?

Comment: I think you mean the substitution $ x=\arctan(t/2) $.

Comment: God,I've forgotten all my basic inverse trigonometric substitution identities. I better dig out my old copy of Strang and review.That's what sucks about doing rigorous math. After awhile,without review, you forget all the plug and chug stuff.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the substitution $x=\arctan(t/2)$ and you will need the identity

> $$ \sin( \arctan(t/2) ) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} $$

to reach the form

> $$ I= \int \frac{t^2}{(t^2+2)(t^2+4)}dt. $$

I think you can finish it now!

Answer (score 6):

Note that $$\frac{\sin^2{x}}{1 + \sin^2{x}} = \frac{1 + \sin^2{x}}{1 + \sin^2{x}} - \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2{x}}$$

The first factor integrates to $x$. For the second integral, note that $$\frac{1}{1 + \sin^2{x}} = \frac{\sec^2{x}}{\tan^2{x} + \sec^2{x}} = \frac{\sec^2{x}}{2\tan^2{x} + 1}$$

Proceed using the substitution $u = \tan{x}$.

Comment: Great answer-especially for a beginner! This is why it's critical to know your trigonometric identities when calculating integrals.

Answer (score -2):

Write the ratio as

$$1- \frac{\cos^2 x}{1+\sin^2 x},$$

and recall that the derivative of $\arctan x$ is $1/(1+x^2)$ to obtain

$$x- 2^{-1/2} \arctan\bigl( \sqrt{2} \tan x\bigr)$$

(plus a constant)

Comment: i think there is a typo.